# install cocos2d for xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I download cocos2d iphone 1.0.0 and cocos2d 1.0.0 beta template for xcode4 and i want use cocos2d in xcode4.

How to install it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your folder that you downloaded and go to:

> Macintosh HD => Developer => Library => Xcode => Templates

Just drop the folder into this templates folder, restart xcode, and you should be good to go!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893476/error-in-cocos2d

Comment: Yeah man, IDK because I am having the same exact problems as you. =(

Answer (score 1):

Download Cocos 2D from 
1) [download Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download)

2) unzip the file

3)Open a Terminal Window Application-> Utilities-> Terminal

4)Type cd  drag and drop the cocos2D unzipped file.

5) Type sudo  drag and drop 'install-templates.sh' file from the downloaded file.

6) Type your password

7) Restart the Xcode then You work with Cocos 2D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1-open cocos2d folder
2-open terminal window
3-type: sudo 
4-and drag and drop file:install-templates.sh     (cocos2d) folder and return

start xcode and new project

Answer (score 0):

If still aries the same problem then following code remove into the script and put all things put into the following path and remove following code into the script.

Path where to put all stuffs

```
Macintosh HD => Developer => Library => Xcode => Templates
```

Remove those code into script

```
# Make sure root is not executed
if [[ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]]; then
echo ""
echo "Error: Do not run this script as root." 1>&2
echo ""
echo "'root' is no longer supported" 1>&2
echo ""
echo "RECOMMENDED WAY:" 1>&2
echo " $0 -f" 1>&2
echo ""
exit 1
```

Then save the install-templates.sh

and then follow following steps.

1)Open a Terminal Window Application-> Utilities-> Terminal

2)Type cd drag and drop the cocos2D unzipped file.

3) Type sudo drag and drop 'install-templates.sh' file from the downloaded file.

3) Type your password

4) Restart the Xcode then You work with Cocos 2D

it's funny but solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was having trouble with this and nothing above worked, I kept getting `"No such file or directory"`.

What worked for me was to `cd` into the `cocos2d` folder that I had unzipped onto my desktop like this:

```
cd Desktop/cocos2d-iphone-2.0/
```

I then ran the install command shell script like so:

```
./install-templates.sh
```

Bingo! Its in! Hope this helps someone.